# Continuously updating colors of one cell based on value in another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with 5 columns (A:E). For each row I wish to color all columns the same color based on the value in A. The colors should be a gradient scale.
Column A is a formula which continuously updates.

I have a solution that goes like this:

1. Make conditional formatting of column A with a Color Scales (red to green)
2. Have vba code monitor changes to the sheet and recolor cells in column B:E based on the values in column A.

The macro looks like this:

```
'Sub to watch value changes
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Range("A2:A19")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("A2:A19")) Is Nothing Then
        color_filters
    End If
End Sub

'Sub to change colors

Public Sub color_filters()
   Dim i as integer
   Dim j as integer
   'Loop through rows then columns
    For i = 2 To 19
        For j = 2 To 5
            Cells(i, j).Interior.color = Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.color
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

The values in A are floats updating with various frequencies.  The values in columns B:E are subordinate.

This solution does the job, but it implies that the ark continuously run the macro thereby disturbing the user of the spreadsheet.

I am therefor seeking a solution, where the macro is run only, when there are changes to the values in column A.

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change` event and condition it for `Target.Column = 1`...

Comment: I would also suggest to change the second iteration of the `color_filters()` sub in just  `Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = Cells(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.color`.